# Remove elements from array using javascript filter

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays and want to remove duplicates using filter function.

**Here is my code:**

```js
arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3];
arr2 = [2, 3];
result = [1, 1];


var result = arr1.filter(function(value, index) {
      for (var i = 0; i <= arr2.length; i++) {
        if (value !== arr2[i]) {

          return value === arr2[i];
        }

      }
    }
```

Thanks in advance! Any help would be great!

Comment: It would be great if can be done using the filter function, if not any answer is fine as long the output is the same.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to convert arguments into array and then check if the value from the initial array is in arguments array:

```
function destroyer(arr) {

  // Converting arguments into array
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

  arr = arr.filter(function (val) {
    return args.includes(val)===false;
  });

    return arr;
}


destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3); // returns[1,1]
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if its not a problem adding a library. I am using **uniq** from [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/).

> uniq_.uniq(array, [isSorted], [iteratee]) Alias: unique
>
> Produces a duplicate-free version of the array, using === to test object
>   equality. In particular only the first occurence of each value is
>   kept. If you know in advance that the array is sorted, passing true
>   for isSorted will run a much faster algorithm. If you want to compute
>   unique items based on a transformation, pass an iteratee function.
>
> _.uniq([1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 3]);
>   => [1, 2, 4, 3]

Other solution is using pure JS:

```
var newArray = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6];
   var unique = newArray.filter(function(itm, i, a) {
      return i == newArray.indexOf(itm);
   });
   alert(unique);
```

But first you will need to combine your arrays in a new array:

```
var newArray = arr1.concat(arr2);
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aju617vj/)

I hope this helped! :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i'm looking for just plain javascript.

Comment: As I mentioned the output should be [1,1] the duplicates 2,3 should be removed. Anyway thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way without the filter function:

```
var arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3];
var newArr = [];
for(var i = 0;i < arr1.length;i++){
    if (newArr.indexOf(arr1[i]) === -1) {
        newArr.push(arr1[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As in this [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/zxw8huq6/), using `filter()`

```js
arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3];
arr2 = [2, 3];
result = [1, 1];


var result = arr1.filter(myFunc);


function myFunc(value) { 
  for (var i = 0; i < arr2.length; ++i) {
    // to remove every occurrence of the matched value
    for (var j = arr1.length; j--;) {
      if (arr1[j] === arr2[i]) {
        // remove the element
        arr1.splice(j, 1);
      }
    }
  }
}
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = arr1;
console.log(arr1);
// Output: [1,1]
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

> The `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

with [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

> The `indexOf()` method returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present.

```js
var arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
    arr2 = [2, 3],
    result = arr1.filter(function (a) {
        return !~arr2.indexOf(a);
    });

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this is great, but having problems understanding the return statement.

Comment: the `!` is a boolean not and the `~` is a bitwise not. so if the element is not in the array, then return true.